# Swift: TableView (inside cell) is not loading cells or code inside cellForRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Why isn't my cell loading data from a tableview inside a cell?

Basically, it runs the `numberOfRowsInSection` function. However, the `cellForRowAt` function is completely ignored and never run.

I can assure you that all my cells are properly linked up, my tableview inside the cell is delegated, and so is the root tableview (I know this as I have other data in the root tableview cell which loads properly).

Would anyone know why the code inside this function doesn't run at all?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SettingsTable: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableTitle: UILabel!

    var TableViewSettingsStruct = SettingsStruct()

    func displayContent(tableViewTitle: String, tableViewIcon: UIImage, settingsStruct: SettingsStruct){
        tableTitle.text = tableViewTitle
        tableIcon.image = tableViewIcon
        TableViewSettingsStruct = settingsStruct
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        //Initialization
        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return TableViewSettingsStruct.cellType.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("Running tableView Code")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "errorCell") as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "An error occurred fetching the cell"
        return cell
    }
}
```

If you notice, I have added a print inside the `cellForRowAt` function. Unlike other tableViews I have implemented, this print statement is not displayed on the console (i.e. it's not run).

Comment: Are you sure that `TableViewSettingsStruct.cellType.count` is greater than `0`?

Comment: May I ask what value `TableViewSettingsStruct.cellType.count` evaluates to?

Comment: Hey there, TableViewSettingsStruct.cellType.count is greater than 0 (in this case it is 3). Even if it was 0, the print statement should be visible in the console, when the app is ran.

Comment: You don't call `reloadData`in `displayContent`.  Also, by convention, it should be `tableViewSettingsStruct` -  small t

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thank you everyone for you help!

I figured out that my tableView had no height constraint set, and once I did set it, the tableView loaded the cell (and therefore the cellForRowAt function).

Sometimes, it can be quite tedious :/